# Running protractor when webdriver-manager start finishes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

I'm having trouble writing a npm script for starting my protractor tests.
Following the documentation https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md seems that first I have to run

```
webdriver-manager start
```

and leave it running while I'm starting the actual tests

```
./node_modules/.bin/protractor test/integration/conf.js
```

I want these two steps to execute inside one npm script, so I would end up with something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "protractor-update": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor-start": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "protractor-init": "npm run protractor-update && npm run protractor-start",
    "test-protractor": "npm run protractor-start && ./node_modules/.bin/protractor test/integration/conf.js",
},
```

Now obviously the problem is that `./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start` doesn't return an exit code so it never makes to the next command.

What would be the proper way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you. This is the solution I found after browsing on StackOverflow and with the help of my colleague.

In package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "e2e": "bash run-e2e-tests.sh"
}
```

---

The bash file:

```
# Start selenium server and trash the verbose error messages from webdriver
webdriver-manager start 2>/dev/null &
# Wait 3 seconds for port 4444 to be listening connections
while ! nc -z 127.0.0.1 4444; do sleep 3; done
#  run protractor
protractor test/e2e/conf.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in shell scripting basics.

Put the webdriver in the background with &

So for example

```
webdriver-manager start &
```

This will run the webdriver-manager and then immediately return control to the shell, allowing you to enter subsequent commands.

You will want to kill the webdriver-manager after the tests are done via some mechanism, such as `kill %1` or `pkill webdriver-manager`. Otherwise you will eventually have dozens of unused webdriver processes running...

Comment: You're assuming that the selenium server will be up when & returns the control to the shell and runs the next command. What if not, the tests will fail, right?

Comment: Speaking about "shell scripting basics" I would recommend you killing the process by its PID rather then picking the first job from the jobs list. You can save the PID of the process recently sent into background with `foo & FOO_PID=$!`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **concurrently** to solve your problem.

Install **concurrently** with following command.

```
npm install concurrently --save
```

Then use in your package.json like below:

```
"e2e:all-steps": "concurrently -k -s first \"./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update\" \"./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start\" \"npm run protractor-update && npm run protractor-start\" \"npm run protractor-start && ./node_modules/.bin/protractor test/integration/conf.js\""
```

Hope that helps. :-)